# Tenacious "Some settings are managed by your organization" messages

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, gpedit

This is not a clone of the '"Some settings are managed by your organization" while not on a domain' question, though they are similar.

I have several settings where the message occurs, notably Windows Update->Advanced Settings, Privacy->Feedback & Diagnostics, and Cortana. These prevent me from following the steps of the given solution to the similar question.

I have looked at the Group Policy Editor as an administrator, but no settings are configured for either the computer or the user. I have checked HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows and noted that
A. Cortana is disabled
B. There is no WindowsUpdate Key

I have some recollection of using the Group Policy Editor to modify these settings to their current state, but since they no longer seem to be in effect, I don't seem to have any way of changing them back.

What's happened and how do I fix it? Is something corrupted, or am I missing something?

Comment: Your question is not clear currently as it is written.

Comment: Edited: Added a more specific question at the end.

Comment: So Cortana is disabled; did you disable it?

Comment: I seem to remember doing that,yes, but the point is that the group policy editor says that cortana is NOT disabled. In short the Group Policy editor does not display the actual policies.

Comment: Home or Professional?

Comment: Professional. gpedit isnt acessable in home.

Comment: It can be added, trivial operation, hence the reason I asked.  Would have explained why Cortana was disabled by the group policy didn't reflect that fact.  Although that could also come from "anti-spy" Windows 10 programs, seen hundreds of people, who totally screwed up their installations because of those programs

Comment: I wen't through gpedit. I disabled cortana because I didn't want to use it, and I didn't want it using resources. Cortana isn't the issue, though.

Comment: Are you running an insiders edition?

Comment: No, that's what I'm trying to fix all this to do.

Comment: You can try resetting all gpo to defaults. Link is for win 7 but its equivalent http://woshub.com/reset-local-group-policies-settings-in-windows/